# Как сгруппировать данные в SQL?

Tags: sql-server, sql

Есть данные вида

```
Заказ | Порядок | Ширина | Высота
A       1         20       31
A       2         21       20
A       3         22       19
B       1         25       27
B       2         21       19
B       3         19       28
```

Нужно вывести

```
Заказ | Ширина | Высота | Ширина | Высота
A       20       31       22       19
B       25       27       19       28
```

т.е нужно сгруппировать по Заказу и вывести для первого и максимального Порядка ширину и высоту. Уже 2 часа бьюсь и что-то подзавис на этом. Подскажите запрос или хотя бы куда копать.

Comment: Идеи есть какие нибудь? я уже 30 минут на SQLFiddle бьюсь над вашим запросом, пока результаты сомнительные...

Comment: В принципе, может действительно использовать временную таблицу. Хотя даже с временной таблицей пока не получилось.

Comment: Пока что застыл в этом [положении][1]. Позже ещё подумаю, работать надо =)

[1]: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4e9459/12

Comment: Может как-нибудь так:

    select a.Заказ, a.Ширина, a.Высота, b.Ширина, b.Высота from
     (select Заказ, Ширина, Высота from tab where Порядок = 1) a join 
     (select Заказ, Ширина, Высота from tab join (select Заказ, max(Порядок) as Порядок
          from tab group by Заказ) c on c.Заказ = tab.Заказ and c.Порядок = tab.Порядок) b 
        on a.Заказ = b.Заказ

Comment: кажется похожий вопрос http://stackoverflow.com/a/14883265/815386

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Схему позаимствовал из комментария. fiddle стал просить денег. Потому привожу здесь:

```
 /*
    drop table dbo.orders
    go
    CREATE TABLE orders 
        (
         name varchar(20), 
         sort_order int,
         width int,
         height int
        );

    INSERT INTO orders
    (name, sort_order, width, height)
    VALUES
    ('A', 1, 20, 31),
    ('A', 2, 21, 20),
    ('A', 3, 22, 19),
    ('B', 1, 25, 27),
    ('B', 2, 21, 19),
    ('B', 3, 19, 28);
    */
    select a.name, a.width, a.height, x.width, x.height from
     (select name, width, height from orders where sort_order = 1) a 
    cross apply 
     (select top 1 name, width, height from orders b
      where a.name=b.name
      order by sort_order desc) x;
```

[CROSS APPLY](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_cross_apply.html)

Comment: Спасибо. Пришел мой босс и сделал на самосоединениях. Пока у нас работает, но довольно медленно. Попробуем это решение, может будет быстрее.